# react hooks and typescript - Property '***' does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have come across this from numerous angles, and currently my code looks like this, and I get the following error:

> Property 'albums' does not exist on type 'never'

I am using React hooks, but getting an error from the `data` object updated with `useState`. `data` has an property `albums` that I am not sure how to define, or where to do this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface ArtistProps {
   artistName: string,
}


const Artist: React.SFC< ArtistProps > = ({ artistName }) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
            <p>{artistName)}</p> // this is fine
            <p>{data.albums}</p> // error here
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: May I ask where did you found that `useState` function? Is it something new or something that old that I've simply missed it's existence?

Comment: @kinduser its from react hooks. You missed the hype train.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<null | {albums: any}>(null);
```

Then use the `data` variable like

```
data!.albums
```

The `!` is to let typescript know that you're sure the value is not `null`. But even better is to explicitely check the value for `null` e.g. `data ? data.albums : 'no data'`

P.S. Instead of `{albums: any}` add your appropriate inerface.

Comment: thanks @Nurbol, I am definitely not a TS expert :-) What would be your suggested solution?